# Where can I remove a desktop in Mission Control?

Tags: mission-control

In Mission Control, I can add a desktop by pushing the button on the top right.

How do I remove a desktop?

Or where in my system preferences do I look to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Enter Mission Control and press <kbd>Option</kbd>. A close button will appear in the top left corner of the miniature views of the desktops:

[image]

Simply press the close button to delete the desktop. Notice that you can't delete Desktop 1.

Comment: @chrisjlee, also if you hover over the Desktop icon for ~ 2 seconds the "x" icon will appear.

Answer (score 0):

If you STILL can't close the "desktops", it may be because you actually just have multiple windows open rather than multiple desktops.  Close the entire program that's multiplying on your mission control and you should see a resolution.

Comment: No, this doesn't work.